# Bootstrap grid not working on dynamic col

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have some data in while loop and it is generating data inside col-md-12 but it is not working as it is supposed to.

```
<div class="row">
while(...) {
<div class="col-md-4">
...
</div>
}
</div>
```

Output is something like

```
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        ..
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        ..

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    ..
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    ..
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
..
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

**I can't put row in while loop otherwise 3 col doesn't appear. Any solution to this problem?**

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify are you using `col-md-4` as shown in the pic, or `col-md-12`?

Comment: sorry I meant col-md-4

Comment: The grid is working perfect. its the CSS that is messing up. you need to sync up the content of these div's with each other like use only two lines or only three lines. If you have random content coming from database which I assume its the case than use substr() function to only show fixed characters say 60-80 characters .

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap column is working here. But here is another problem.

There is 'float:left;' in Bootstrap column. That's why it is very much important to make same height of your boxes.

So just confirm that all boxes height is same and your problem will be solved.

Comment: They are not as content is them is dynamically generated. How to make it same height?

Comment: In the box  the height of header tag and p tag may vary. So use - 

h2{
height: your choice;
overflow:hidden;
}
p{
height: your choice;
overflow:hidden;
}